# Inconsistent behaviour of SAPUI5 app on Android Lollipop (5.0)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sapui5, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a sapui5 application that works fine on Android kitkat and iOS. I have used phonegap 2.9 to run it on android and iOS. I have an app that contains all the views. On login, it goes to the home view that has a tile conatainer inside a page. Tap on tile navigates to another page. This works fine on iOS and android kitkat but the navigation does not work on android 5.0(lollipop). Remote debugging shows no error in the code. When I return tile container instead of page, it works once or twice but stops working after that.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Latest libraries
2. Avoid unnecessary files in your 'www' folder.
3. Change the code according to the latest version of UI5 .

I faced a similar issue and it was resolved after I followed the above mentioned steps.